# Save an uploaded jsx file locally and then display that file in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, file-upload, tailwind-css

I am tasked to build an component which asks the user to upload a game built in react (jsx in particular). After the game is uploaded it is supposed to be saved inside the project directory so that it could be used later to display and play the game. I am able to upload the game, but i have to direction what to do next, if i should convert it into json or blob or what. I am attaching the code i have done below. Kindly help me out

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function AddGame() {
    const [game, setGame] = useState();
    const [gameFile, setGameFile] = useState();
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setGame({ ...game, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        // console.log(game);
    }

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setGameFile([...e.target.files])
        setLoaded(true);
        console.log(e.target.files)
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(gameFile)

    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container mx-auto w-fit">
                <div>
                    <h3 className="text-center text-white text-4xl my-4 font-semibold">New Game</h3>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="shadow p-8 my-4 bg-zinc-200 rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center lg:w-[50rem] w-[30rem]">
                        <div className="mb-4 mt-2 flex align-top w-full">
                            <label className="text-zinc-900 font-semibold inline-block w-48">Game Title: </label>
                            <textarea onChange={handleChange} rows="1" minLength="3" maxLength="30" className="shadow rounded p-2 text-zinc-900 resize-none w-full" name="gameTitle" placeholder="Write title here" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4 mt-2 flex align-top w-full">
                            <label className="text-zinc-900 font-semibold inline-block w-48">Game Description: </label>
                            <textarea onChange={handleChange} rows="5" minLength="10" maxLength="1024" className="shadow rounded p-2 text-zinc-900 resize-none w-full" name="gameDescription" placeholder="Write description here" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="mb-4 mt-2 flex align-top w-full">
                            <label className="text-zinc-900 font-semibold inline-block w-48">Add  Game File: </label>
                            <input
                                type="file"
                                className="text-zinc-900 w-full"
                                accept=".jsx, .js"
                                multiple
                                name="gameFile"
                                onChange={handleFileChange} />
                        </div>
                        <button className="border-2 rounded-lg h-12 px-4 py-2 border-neutral-600 bg-neural-600/[.20] transition duration-200 hover:bg-neutral-600 hover:text-white text-zinc-900 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:cursor-not-allowed">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div >
            </div >
        </>

    );
}
```

Comment: please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663597/6651840)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thank you for your response but, that was not of much help. I have made some progress and now i am able to read the uploaded file as text. Now i have to find a way to render it as component. And just fyi i have the option to upload an html or simple js file also.